# Remove the vertical indicator line from Activity Bar in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks, code-editor

How can I remove [the vertical indicator line from Activity Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmjWC.png) in VS code's new release?

[image: example image]

How can the vertical line of the indicator be removed from the side of the activity bar in vs code, so it does not exist like in the previous version? I prefer the earlier version so the activity bar indicator does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to deactivate it. You could try to override the `activityBar.activeBorder` setting of your color theme. To do so, open your settings (`Ctrl+Shift+P` -> `Preferences`) and add a new entry:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "activityBar.activeBorder": "#000000"
}
```

Instead of `#000000` use e.g. the the value of `activityBar.background` of your current theme.
To see what you current theme is look for `workbench.colorTheme` in your settings.

Comment: Thank you dear friend. Hopefully in the future settings there will be a way to disable and delete it, this vertical line is too nerve-wracking and very ugly. In my opinion, this feature is of little value because it is self-sufficient enough to change the active part of the paint compared to the other parts.

Comment: Your welcome. Well, I like this feature as it helps me to better recognize which activity is open. But I would definitely like to see an option to simply enable/disable it.

Comment: Or just make it transparent:  `   "activityBar.activeBorder": "#0000",`